# Using IDs in the help texts

Tags: feature-request

I would sometimes like to point out particular text within a help text e.g. the "Answer well-asked questions" section in the [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) text on StackOverflow (or the same text on U&L).

However since non of the sections have IDs I cannot do so using `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#some_id`. Can we get IDs on the sections e.g. of the form: all-lowercase section name, with space reverted to underscore?

This should not significantly slow down the download of the help text page, and it enables pointing out relevant help more specifically.